# How do I allow a blank option in a form when the model doesn't allow it (in django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model, like this:

```
class Cert(models.Model):
    COUNTY_CHOICES = (
        ('Choice1', 'Choice1'),
        ('Choice2', 'Choice2'),
        )
    someField = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=COUNTY_CHOICES)
```

Then I have a form, like this:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    someField = forms.CharField(max_length=12, required=False)
    county = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Cert.COUNTY_CHOICES, required=False)
```

I want my search form to allow a "blank" or "all" option, but I don't want my model to allow it.  Is there a way to do this or do I have to create another list of CHOICES? I tried making it not required in the form, and I tried adding an "initial" setting, neither of which solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build another choices tuple from `COUNTY_CHOICES`, and use that in your form.

```
search_choices = (('', ''),) + Cert.COUNTY_CHOICES
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I was thinking there might be some built-in solution for this (I tried required=False, which didn't work obviously).

Comment: `ModelChoiceFields` have an `empty_label` option, but in this case you have to do it yourself. Luckily, it's not too tricky ;-)

Comment: It seems like this is really designed to map a foreignkey type relationship.  If I understand this answer, I think I would need to create a table that just held the choices (and use that table in the queryset), but I don't think that's very elegant.  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Sorry if my previous comment was confusing. I wasn't suggesting that you use a model choice field in this case ... it was just a remark that the model choice field has a built in `empty_label` option, unlike the choice field. Storing the counties in the databases has its advantages (e.g. users can update them rather than relying on you to change the code), but that's off topic for this question.